# Appending instances of an object to a list only works with time consuming deepcopy, how can I change this?

Tags: python, list, deep-copy

I have a pymzml.run.Reader class from the pymzml package. This is a generator object, when looping through it it yields instances of the Spectrum class (also from the pymzml package). I'm comparing different instances with each other. Because pymzml.run.Reader is a generator object, after looping through them they can't be used anymore, so I save them in a list for comparison later on.

However, when I save them in a list and then loop through the list printing the id's of the spectra, it shows that it only save the last spectrum. To clarify:

```
import pymzml

def test(msrun):
    for spectrum in msrun:
        print spectrum['id']            
        spectrumList.append(spectrum)
    print '-'*20
    for i in spectrumList:
        print i['id']

msrun = pymzml.run.Reader(r'JG_Ti02-C1-1_C2-01A_file1.aligned.mzML')
```

gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
--------------------
5
5 
5 
5
5
```

The pymzml has a deRef() function that makes a deepcopy of the spectrum, so the following does work correctly:

```
import pymzml

def test(msrun):
    for spectrum in msrun: 
        print spectrum['id']
        spectrumList.append(spectrum.deRef())

msrun = pymzml.run.Reader(r'JG_Ti02-C1-1_C2-01A_file1.aligned.mzML')
```

However, making deepcopies is a major bottleneck which I'm trying to get out of my application. How can I append the spectrum instances to a list so that not only the last spectrum is appended multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be just saving the last spectrum -- you're doing all the right things to save each object to the list.

The problem is you're getting the same object over and over.

Printing `id(spectrum)` in the loop to get its memory address will show that it is one object repeated with its `id` and other attributes changed.

While you don't necessarily need `copy.deepcopy()`, you do need to make a copy. Try `copy.copy()`, and look at the source of `Spectrum.decRef()` to see how it does its copying.

Most likely, you do need to `decRef()` each one to make them independent -- otherwise, why would the class provide a special method?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's the same memory address. Spectrum.deRef() uses deepcopy and strips them of some information, it just takes such a big time.. Anyway, thanks for your answer.